# Collapse use in xml schema

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

In xml schema there i have following for an element

```
    <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
```

What i saw in w3schools.com is that

"The whiteSpace constraint is set to "collapse", which means that the XML processor WILL REMOVE all white space characters (line feeds, tabs, spaces, carriage returns are replaced with spaces, leading and trailing spaces are removed, and multiple spaces are reduced to a single space)"

I have found that during xml validation against the schema(by using stylus studio and visual studio) if that element has more than one space or newline feed etc then validation don't gives error.So what does collapse mean? Is it tells the element should not have more than one space,tab etc(but in validation no error came) or it is something else?

Update:
So does this collapse is used in validation of xml only?

xml parser compulsorily removes those space while processing?

Is there any other problems if the xml has white space chars more than one and collapse specified for that element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that whitespace should be normalized or collapsed for a string before other validation is carried out. For example you might specify the facet `<xs:pattern value="\d{3}"/>`, and the value `"    999    "` would be valid if whitespace is set to collapse, because the whitespace would be removed before the value is tested against the pattern.

Comment: I had some more doubts. so i have updated my question. So please have a look at it.

Comment: The removal of whitespace also affects the value that is held in the PSVI. Whether this affects you depends on how you are processing the data; for example I've no idea whether JAXB presents the collapsed value or the original. I can give you an answer for XPath/XSLT/XQuery (but it's not a simple one and is to some extent implementation-defined...)